# Not able to call function with two return variables

Tags: kotlin

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3OQ4.png)
I'm new to Kotlin, I have successfully called a function returning two variables else where in my code but it give an error when used as shown. Everything worked until I decided I wanted to return two variables. I can get it to work if I use if then statements but that isn't as clean. Is there a way to do this using a lambda? It tells me the first value is expression unused and the second that a boolean is expected.

```
fun block (puzzle: Array<IntArray>, x:Int, y:Int): Pair<MutableList<Int>, MutableSet<Int>> {
    var blockNums: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
    var blockNumsFinal: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()
    when {
        ((x in 0..2) and (y in 0..2)) -> (blockNums, blockNumsFinal) = getBlock1(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 3..5) and (y in 0..2)) -> blockNums = getBlock2(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 6..8) and (y in 0..2)) -> blockNums = getBlock3(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 0..2) and (y in 3..5)) -> blockNums = getBlock4(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 3..5) and (y in 3..5)) -> blockNums = getBlock5(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 6..8) and (y in 3..5)) -> blockNums = getBlock6(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 0..2) and (y in 6..8)) -> blockNums = getBlock7(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 3..5) and (y in 6..8)) -> blockNums = getBlock8(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 6..8) and (y in 6..8)) -> blockNums = getBlock9(puzzle, x, y)
    }
    return Pair(blockNums, blockNumsFinal)
}
```

I have found no answers in my google searches.

Comment: Please post the code as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: Difficult to tell from a single screenshot, but it's possible [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html#example-destructuring-declarations-and-maps) is what you want. Kotlin doesn't have the ability to return multiple values from a function. It returns a `Pair` which happens to contain two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
(blockNums, blockNumsFinal) =
```

looks like you're trying to use a destructuring *declaration* syntax for variables that are already declared. This is not allowed. You can only use it for declarations (hence the name).

Since your other function evidently already returns a pair, this should work, but I'm guessing because I'm not sure of the return types of your other functions.

You're also misusing the `and` infix function. It is intended for bitwise comparisons. When used with Boolean expressions, it prevents early-exiting of the total expression, which means if the first expression is false, it still redundantly calculates the second expression. Not what you want here. You should use `&&` here.

```
fun block (puzzle: Array<IntArray>, x:Int, y:Int): Pair<MutableList<Int>, MutableSet<Int>> {
    return when {
        ((x in 0..2) && (y in 0..2)) -> getBlock1(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 3..5) && (y in 0..2)) -> getBlock2(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 6..8) && (y in 0..2)) -> getBlock3(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 0..2) && (y in 3..5)) -> getBlock4(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 3..5) && (y in 3..5)) -> getBlock5(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 6..8) && (y in 3..5)) -> getBlock6(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 0..2) && (y in 6..8)) -> getBlock7(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 3..5) && (y in 6..8)) -> getBlock8(puzzle, x, y)
        ((x in 6..8) && (y in 6..8)) -> getBlock9(puzzle, x, y)
        else -> Pair(mutableListOf(), mutableSetOf())
    }
}
```

About the syntax you were trying to use, that would be called "destructuring *assignment*" if it existed. [There's a feature request on the Kotlin YouTrack page for it.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11362)